# Difference between "wave AT" and "wave TO"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, differences

What's the difference between "wave" used with "to" and "wave" used with "at"?

Two sentences as examples:

> She's waving at the person behind me.

and

> The lookout man had waved to me as I approached.

Could either choice be used in each sentence?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the most part, I believe, they are interchangeable and both choices are idiomatic in most cases.

Personally, I would wave *to* someone when I'm greeting them and wave *at* someone when I'm merely gesturing in their direction to get their attention. But reversing them doesn't really sound *wrong* to me, so I don't think the distinction is truly very significant.

Comment: I would agree with your subtle distinction. I'd say a traffic cop waves *at* motorists, not *to* them; the latter might imply he's saying hello rather than directing traffic.

Answer (score 5):

After looking through some corpus examples via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (and BNC and GloWBe), I would say that the two are mostly equivalent. Just some notes:

- For some reason, "wave to" is used more often. (It's hard to judge exactly how much more often because of false positives, however.)
- While not used with humans with this exact meaning due to the potential for confusion, "wave at" can be used where "wave away" would also be idiomatic, as a gesture of dismissal or annoyance:

  > "Nothing," he said, waving at the question in a way that suggested he'd fended it off several times — [NYT](https://archive.nytimes.com/opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/11/15/hollywood-dreams/)

  > I dangle my hand in the sand below the camp bed and wave at the flies buzzing around my head. — Ardnish Was Home

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to give additional insights to @Heartspring's answer.

According to the third point in the preposition section of Wiktionary's ["at"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at#Preposition) entry:

> In the direction of (often in a hostile or careless manner).

It further states some usage notes, highlighting the difference in nuance in some examples:

> He threw the ball to me (so I could catch it)
> He threw the ball at me (trying to hit me with it)

Another example to illustrate the other carried nuance:

> He talked to her (conversationally)
> He shouted at her (agressively)

So we could interpret "wave at" as "carelessly waving to someone".

In a similar way, we have the following definition in the second point of Wiktionary's ["to"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to#Preposition) entry:

> Used to indicate the target or recipient of an action.

In other words, comparing it to the usage of "at", it doesn't carry any additional nuance to the action of "waving".

---

Do notice that the definition of "at" does not mean that it always has to carry this nuance. Thus, both terms are often used interchangeably.
This idea has been corroborated by @Heartspring, but I will leave a link to the TheFreeDictionary's ["wave at someone"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wave+at+(someone+or+something)) entry, where it defines both "wave at someone" and "wave to someone" to mean the same:

> To move an upraised hand in such a way as to signal recognition to someone.